# Does an unconscious dying creature with regeneration regain its actions on its following turn?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, actions, unconscious, regeneration

## A matter of order?

While seeming like an easy question, it might actually be a bit more convoluted.

The way I see it, the question comes down to the order of following two aspects:

- Regaining actions
- Regeneration bringing the creature above 0 HP

On the subject of gaining actions:

> **Single actions** can be completed in a very short time. ... During an encounter, you get 3 actions at the beginning of your turn, which you can use as described on page 468. Core Rulebook pg. 461 errata 4.0
> [Archive of Nethys](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=387)

On the subject of regeneration:

> A creature with fast healing or regeneration regains the listed amount of Hit Points each round at the beginning of its turn. Core Rulebook pg. 461 errata 4.0 [Arcive of Nethys](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=796)

Thus: **does** the unconscious dying creature regain hit points before regaining its actions, and thus can it act on its next turn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes

> At the start of each of your turns, take these steps in any order you choose:
>
> - [...]
> - Do anything else that is specified to happen at the start of your turn, such as **regaining Hit Points** from fast healing or **regeneration**.
>
> **The last step of starting your turn** is always the same.
>
> **Regain your 3 actions and 1 reaction**. If you haven't spent your reaction from your last turn, you lose it—you can't “save” actions or reactions from one turn to use during the next turn. Some abilities or conditions (such as quickened, slowed, and stunned) can change how many actions you regain and whether you regain your reaction. If you lose actions and gain additional actions (such as if you're both quickened and slowed), you choose which actions to lose. In-depth details on gaining and losing actions are here

Actions are gained after all other ["start/beginning of turn" effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=436)